# Remove Listbox Items With Checkboxes

Tags: c#, linq, checkbox, listbox

I *am* aware of the question asked by user ElPeta. However the selected answer to *his* question does not fix my issue.

In my program I have a list box, whenever a check box is clicked and its checked property set to true, the list box is populated with text, however when the check box is unchecked, I want to remove the text associated with the check box from the list box.

Example Before and After:

[image: Before][image: After]

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CarFinderByMake
{
    public partial class frmCFBM : Form
    {
        public frmCFBM()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'honestRalphsUsedCarsDataSet.tblCars' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tblCarsTableAdapter.Fill(this.honestRalphsUsedCarsDataSet.tblCars);

        }

        private void chkFord_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkFord.Checked)
            {
                //lstCarMakes.Items.Clear();
                //populating the listbox
                var fordCars = from x in honestRalphsUsedCarsDataSet.tblCars where x.Make.StartsWith("Ford") select x;
                foreach (var x in fordCars)
                {
                    lstCarMakes.Items.Add(x.ModelYear + " " + x.Make + " - " + x.Color);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int x = 0; x <= lstCarMakes.Items.Count; ++x )
                {
                    //here I was attempting to find the index of the items...
                    if (lstCarMakes.Items.Contains("Ford"))
                    {
                        lstCarMakes.Items.IndexOf("Ford");
                        //and after that I was going to remove the items.
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox3.Checked)
            {
                //lstCarMakes.Items.Clear();
                //populating the list box
                var cadillacCars = from x in honestRalphsUsedCarsDataSet.tblCars where x.Make.StartsWith("Cadillac") select x;
                foreach (var x in cadillacCars)
                {
                    lstCarMakes.Items.Add(x.ModelYear + " " + x.Make + " - " + x.Color);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does not work when you try to remove the item?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I could not figure out how to take the indices gathered and use them to refer to the lines I wanted to remove.

Comment: Replace the word "Ford" with the Text or Tag value in the CheckBox.  You are looping but aren't using the loop variable.  `lstCarMakes.Items[x]`.  Also, loop backwards, because once you remove an item, the count gets reduced, and your indexes are off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ListBox.ObjectCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection(v=vs.100).aspx) returned from `ListBox.Items` has methods `Remove(obj)` and `RemoveAt(index)`. You can loop it backwards and use `RemoveAt`:

```
private void chkFord_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (chkFord.Checked)
    {
        // you have it working ...
    }
    else
    {
        for (int x = lstCarMakes.Items.Count - 1; x >= 0; x-- )
        {
            string car = lstCarMakes.Items[x].ToString();
            if(car.IndexOf("Ford", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
               lstCarMakes.Items.RemoveAt(x);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also used `String.IndexOf` instead of `Contains` to support case-insensitivity.

Comment: Does `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` have any prerequisites?

Comment: @EvanManning: No. You can also use `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`. Doesn't make a great difference here. Here is the enum: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Than it is odd, because it will not let me use it, It says that `System.StringComparison` doesn't have a definition for it.

Comment: @EvanManning: have you really used `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` because in the first version there was a small typo. You can also use intellisense in visual-studio to let you help.

Comment: Ok, it was the lowercase "c".

Comment: @EvanManning: just to clarify, you can use `Contains`, but then it won't find `ford` but only `Ford`. That's why i have shown you this approach. More important is the backwards loop that you need if you want to remove items via index while you loop this collection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your specific error, but I imagine you might have an issue since you're using the item count of the listbox, and removing the items. When the item gets deleted the item count is changed. I believe there's a method for list box such as listbox.BeginUpdate()  you can call before making changes to the items within the listbox and listbox.Update() after you're finished. Let me know if I'm in the right area with your problem

Comment: I am not using the Item count but that was what I was attempting to do.